# $(window).width() not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, cross-browser

I am doing something like follow:

```
// get the screen height and width 
var maskHeight = $(document).height(); 
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

// calculate the values for center alignment
var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2);
```

But looks like it's not working in IE9.

Comment: What exactly is it doing wrong?

Comment: he is somehow shifting to right

Comment: @Saurabh You should cache your `$('#dialog-box')` reference: `var dialog = $('#dialog-box')[0];` (on page load), and then `$(dialog)` whenever you need it...

Comment: @Saurabh `$(window).width()` should work just fine. The problem is somewhere else... Can you provide a screenshot of the issue?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var maskWidth = window.innerWidth;
var maskHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

Or in IE 6+ in standards compliant mode:

```
var maskWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var maskHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$(window).innerHeight();
$(window).innerWidth();
```

Comment: Doesn't work on the window object... (The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) clearly state that)