# $(window).width() not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(window).width() not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016268/window-width-not-working-in-ie9)

I'm trying to do some DOM manipulation for responsive web design. In IE this is not working.

```
var w = $(document).width(); 

if (w > 940) {
console.log("If test");     
} else {
console.log("Else test");
```

If I use  window.width, it works in IE but stop working in other browsers. Is there a cross browser way for that?

Comment: I'm using $( window ).height() for a home page feature that sizes sections of the page to match the viewport height, and this works across browsers. Can you setup a fiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
var maskWidth = window.innerWidth;
var maskHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

As per, [$(window).width() not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016268/window-width-not-working-in-ie9)

Comment: Thank. I think window.innerWidth is not working in Opera, but it works in IE

Answer (score 2):

Responsive designs should be done in CSS with media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width:940px) {
    /* some style rules that should be put in place
       if the window is smaller than 940px wide */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it's not possible in my case. For mobile view, it going to be a simple html content line by line, and for desktop view, this html part is going to be a dynamic carousel/tabbed slider.

Answer (score 2):

There is an inherent problem with your approach, and that is that "responsive" refers to the design responding to a change in size. With what you are doing here, you only get a detection when the browser loads.

Say, for example, you are using an iPhone to view this site and you turn the phone 45 degrees to landscape instead of portrait. Essentially, your width just changed but your width() didn't.

There are a couple of options I would recommend looking at if you need to use javascript for your DOM manipulation and can't accomplish it with pure CSS (which is generally the best way to go):

1. Check out the proposed matchMedia() method by Rob Tarr http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/responsive_web_design_and_javascript
2. Use http://modernizr.com/ or some other library that has already solved this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for very useful links. Reading... I am going to  have my js working not when page loads only, but also on event that detects width change.